# How to overlap text or image on video file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video, flutter-video-player

I want to edit the video file and overlap the text or image on this like an Instagram story.

Comment: Use a `Stack` .

Comment: Thank you @iDecode for the response but I want to save the video file after overlap text or image.

Comment: Did you find solution ?